# Paillier scheme and noise growth

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, paillier

Does the problem of noise growth exist in the Paillier homomorphic scheme ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the problem of noise growth exist in the Paillier homomorphic scheme ?

No, it does not.  Unlike Lattice-based schemes, you can do as many homomorphic additions as you want in Paillier (without doing anything like a "reboot"), and it's never a problem.

Comment: Yes. It must sometime be taken into account that the homomorphic property of the Paillier scheme is modulo $N$.

Comment: Thanks .. can you explain the relation with the noise growth ?

Comment: @witdev: The value $g^x r^n \bmod n^2$ is a valid encryption of the plaintext $x$ (for any $0 < r < n$, $r$ r.p. to $n$.  The multiplication of the two ciphertexts $g^x r^n \bmod n^2$ and $g^y r'^n \bmod n^2$ is thus $g^{x+y} (rr')^n \bmod n^2$, and thus is always a valid encryption of $x+y \bmod n$.  This always holds, and hence there is no 'noise growth'; the interaction of the random values $r, r'$ never interferes with the decryption process (and so you don't run into the same problems you do with Lattice based systems)

Comment: Paillier is a encryption scheme based on the number theroy and there is non-existing noise like lattice-based cryptography.